# What's the disadvantage of increasing the size of an EBS instance in Amazon EC2?

Tags: web-server, amazon-ec2, cloud-computing

I used the default ebs Ubuntu image from Alestic.com
But the volume is only 8GB.
Is there any disadvantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not particularly. I think 8gb is the default size for an EBS volume.

Comment: What's the max size? Can I make it 500GB?

Comment: The max is 1TB, if you want to make it 500gb, go for it! :)

Comment: oh, just a friendly reminder, if my answer helped, please hit that checkbox next to my post to mark it as the answer. thanks!

Comment: Oh Nice. Do larger volumes cost more? I think EC2 only charges based on hourly usage and traffic, right? I have to wait 8 minutes until I can check your answer. I will do.

Comment: Yes and no. If you provision a 500GB instance but only use 40GB, you are charged only for the 40gb you used, not the whole 500GB you provisioned.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you're doing with it.
Planning on keeping more than 6GiB of logs?

The larger the volume, the higher the failure rate. Although I've not tested it myself, rumor has it that 1TiB volumes provide the best performance.

Make sure you snapshot regularly as reliability is linked to dirty blocks.